# Copy-Constructor - Compiler-Error C2040 and C2440

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, copy-constructor

I am getting a few compiler errors that are originating from my Copy-Constructor. I understand that the first error is due to incompatible operand types, I just am not sure of a better way to write that code. And the second error I am not sure about at all. Why wouldn't `'='` be able to convert from Node* to Node*?

Any help or direction would be appriciated.

Thanks!

```
// Copy-Constructor
List::List(const List& theList)
{
    Node* tempPtr = new Node;
    tempPtr = theList.first;

//error C2040: 'tempPtr' : 'List' differs in levels of indirection from 'Node *'
    List(tempPtr);

    while (tempPtr != NULL)
    {
        Node* copyNode = new Node;

//error C2440: '=' :cannot convert from 'Node *' to 'Node *'
        copyNode = tempPtr;

        tempPtr = tempPtr->getNext();
        nodeListTotal++;
    }
}
```

Below is my constructor and destructor.

```
List::List():first(0), last(0), nodeListTotal(0)
{
}

// Destructor
List::~List()
{
    Node* currentNode = first;

    while(currentNode != NULL) 
    {
        Node* temp = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->getNext();
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the first line 'List(tempPtr);' where do you define that constructor? It may be that that error is causing the second error. More over you have a really obvious leak. You allocate copyNode  in your loop and then attempt to overwrite it with tempPtr. Why?

Comment: This is my first attempt at building a linked-list and the copy-constructor is throwing me off. It looks like I haven't defined `List(tempPtr)` in the constructor and I am trying to copy the first node in the List, which is why i am overwriting copyNode with tempPtr.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `List(tempPtr);`? Even if you had a `List(Node*)` constructor, it is unlikely that call is doing what you want to do.

Comment: Memory leak here:     `Node* tempPtr = new Node; tempPtr = theList.first;` - you are allocating a new node, then overwriting it with the `first` in `theList`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. First, the C2040 and the C2440 where the types are the same type. Based on what I found [in this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++/6fv5E1DHALc), parentheses are allowed in a declaration, so the statement:

```
List(tempPtr);
```

is apparently equivalent to:

```
List tempPtr;
```

Therefore the error is an extremely confusing way of saying you redeclared the variable `tempPtr`, and you gave it a different type. But note that if you wrote `List*(tempPtr)` it would say `redefinition: different basic types`, so it also seems to have to do with the fact that `List` is not as much of a pointer as `Node*` (that's where the "levels of indirection" bit comes from). The C2440 occurs because of the redeclaration. You can confirm this by commenting out `List(tempPtr);` and seeing that the code will compile. However, the fact that it will compile is not to say it is in any way correct.

Problem #2 is that you don't show here a constructor taking a `Node*`, and even if you had one, that wouldn't be the right way to call it. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with that.

Problem #3 is that you are leaking `Node` objects like crazy. When you execute the lines:

```
Node* tempPtr = new Node;
tempPtr = theList.first;
```

and

```
Node* copyNode = new Node;
copyNode = tempPtr;
```

you are allocating `Node` objects and then throwing away the pointers to them. If you are trying to copy the `Node` objects, that isn't the way to do it. You need a copy constructor there, too.

This is not everything that goes into a correct copy constructor for your `List` class, but it covers some of the biggest problems with the code you've posted, and especially this seems to be why you are getting those two errors.

Answer (score 0):

The situation looks like a combination of some sort of misunderstanding on your part and a compiler bug.

Formally statement

```
 List(tempPtr);
```

must be interpreted by the compiler as a declaration

```
 List tempPtr;
```

The language specification in clearly states in 6.8 (C++03) that ambiguity between declaration and functional cast expression must be resolved in favor or declaration. That means that what you have there is an illegal redeclaration of variable `tempPtr`. You already declared `tempPtr` before with a different type.

However, the error message issued by the compiler seems to suggest that the compiler interpreted it as a functional cast expression (instead of a declaration). This expression attempts to create a nameless temporary object of type `List` from a pointer `tempPtr` of type `Node *`. That temporary object (if successfully created) is then immediately destroyed. However, class `List` does not have a constructor that can construct it from `Node *` pointer. This is what the compiler is telling you. Your class `List` has only one single-parameter constructor, which takes `const List &`, while you supplied a `Node *`. The compiler is telling you that it can't convert `Node *` to `List` to invoke that constructor.

Still, regardless of how one interprets that statement (expression or declaration), it makes no sense in the context of your code. It is broken in either case. So, basically, the question is: what on Earth are you trying to do with that `List(tempPtr);` line? What was your intent?

The second error is probably induced by the first one.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong about the compiler interpreting it as a cast (that was my initial thought), but the error occurs and the text is the same even if `List` has a ctor taking `Node*` - I tried it.

Comment: @Joel: Good point. I tried it too and indeed adding the corresponding constructor does not help. Moreover, removing the `()` around the variable name does not change the error message. That probably means that the compiler interprets it correctly - as a declaration, but the error message it issues is a bit misleading and/or confusing. The bottom line is that the code is invalid, so the question of what you were trying to do by that line still remains.